# Symfony3 Forms: How to know which button was clicked in the form?

Tags: php, controller, symfony, symfony-forms

**Symfony3 Forms:** I have managed to build and render the form as shown below:

```
<form action="/member/john/actions" method="post" name="form">
    <input type="submit" value="Block John" name="block">
    <input type="submit" value="Remove from my friends" name="remove">
    <input type="hidden" value="LeiajURspTa9c8JEUYtvepki0b_CdL9dMWqEZxOYvfk" name="form[_token]" id="form__token">
</form>
```

When I click the the buttons `"Block John"` or `"Remove from my friends"`, the controller routes it to the desired location *(member_friend_actions)* and it is able to show the *debug dump values* along with `"Submitted!"` text, before dying.

My controller with route "member_friend_actions" is set-up as shown below:

```
/**
 * A common post location to catch all operations like add/remove/cancel/block friends
 *
 * @Route("/{username}/actions", name="member_friend_actions")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function allActionsFriendAction(Request $request, User $friend)
{
    $form = $this->createAllActionsFriendForm($friend);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        //$clicked = $form->getData();
        $clicked = $form->getClickedButton()
        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($clicked);            
        die("Submitted!");

    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('member_profile', array("username" => $friend->getUsername()));
}
```

I want to know which button was clicked that brought it here (block or remove here; but there can be more buttons in other places). I tried using the methods:

> $form->getData() => which gives array(0) { } and
>   $form->getClickedButton() => gives NULL, so are not helping.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Hi there Ren. If my answer did 'solve' the problem, also please click the checkmark besides my answer to mark it as the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It depends how you added the SubmitType to your form.
For example if you used something like this:

```
->add('block_john', SubmitType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Block John'
))
```

Then in your controller you can then use something like:

```
$form->get('block_john')->isClicked()
```

See this link for more info:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/multiple_buttons.html

Comment: Perhaps because I did not create all buttons with a single form builder object, `->isClicked()` did not return true in my case. So I tried something similar that worked.

Answer (score -1):

Since I did not create all the buttons at once using `->add()` notation, but were produced with if-else-if-else conditions and calling corresponding methods as shown below:

> $form = $this->createCancelFriendForm($user);
>
> $addFriendForm = $form->createView();

perhaps this was reason that function like `$form->getData()`, `$form->getClickedButton()`, `$form->get('block')->isClicked()` returned empty values.

But because this form was still getting through the validation and into successfully *Submitted* case; I simply tried using the `if(isset($_POST["block"])) {}` equivalent of Symfony like so:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    if ($request->request->get("block")) {
            // Pass it over to corresponding block handler
            $response = $this->forward('AppBundle:Member:blockFriend', array(
                   'friend'  => $friend,
            ));
        return $response;
    }

    if ($request->request->get("unblock")) {
        // Pass it over to corresponding unblock handler
        $response = $this->forward('AppBundle:Member:unBlockFriend',
            array(
                    'friend'  => $friend,
            ));
        return $response;
    }

    // I can add n number of other checks ( eg: add, remove, accept)
    // here and add their handlers as above
}
```

...which worked for me as desired. B)